# Problem with creat mysql connection through ODI

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I need to create MYSQL connection through ODI with JDBC connection but I need some help for do this. according to ODI topology I have to fill this JDBC URL with my info:

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>[:<port>]/[<database>]?relaxAutoCommit=true[&<property>=<value>...]

my DB info is:
ip address: 10.5.6.77
port:3304
username: root
password: rewcvt4567
database name: accdb

my os info is:
ip address: 10.5.6.77
port:22
username: root
password: dfrtvb6784
```

I should say, SSh tunnel has been enabled on my server.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do us just fill this with host, port and service name

jdbc:mysql://[:]/[]

in your case it will be

jdbc:mysql://10.5.6.77:3304/accdb

in definition connection fill it with
username: root
password: rewcvt4567

Comment: What to you mean in definition connection? In ODI studio, topology tab there is an option for connecting to db via jdbc connection. I think because of ssh which running on the server, I should consider to OS credential as well.

Comment: when you create data server above the JDBC tab there is a definition (on page you give the name of dataserver)